# Triple Boot Windows 10, Kali Linux & Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, kali

I have two m.2 SSDs on my laptop, the 500gb ssd that is installed runs Windows 10 and the other 250gb, I plan to split 150gb Kali Linux & 100gb Ubuntu.

I am a novice linux user, can anyone share with me the full steps on how to triple boot all 3 OS to work properly together by using Ubuntu Grub (Not Kali Linux Grub)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Install Ubuntu last, OR boot Ubuntu and `sudo grub-install /dev/...`  (it'll install the MBR or grub's first stage on MBR on drive (device) you specify)

Comment: @guiverc I have a few questions I would like to ask. 1) Is it possible to install Kali Linux n Ubuntu when the SSD that has windows 10 installed on is plugged into the system? Will it cause any issues? 2) For partitioning wise, I will be creating /boot, /root, /home & /swap for both Kali n Ubuntu right? (Are there any other partitions required?) Or do I not need any of the above repeating partitions? 3) there is a prompt "force UEFI installation" do I select yes or no? 4) for bootloader itself, where do I point it to? Windows or Ubuntu drive?

Comment: While you can install Kali, it really is intended to be on a flash (pen) drive. I do belive it needs a lot of space. Best not to use /boot  & swap with Ubuntu. Ubuntu now uses a swap file. Do not share partitions. If you want to share some data create data partitions. If Windows is UEFI, then you should install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. Be sure drive is gpt partitioned if you partition in advance. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: @oldfred I use etcher to create a live image for Ubuntu & Kali. Will there be a need to remove the SSD for windows 10 before installing both Linux OS?

Comment: If you are "a novice linux user", you may want to read [Should I Use Kali Linux?](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux).

Comment: Many new systems now let you logically disconnect a drive in UEFI settings, so you do not have to open case to disconnect a drive. You do not have to disconnect drive, but Ubuntu will install grub by default into the ESP - efi system partition of first drive it sees, usually the Windows existing ESP. You should partition in advance to be sure to have ESP on Linux drive. You then can reinstall grub and/or copy boot files from Windows drive's ESP to Linux drive's ESP..